# Importing excel file into db (Takes a lot of time)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, epplus, import-from-excel

I am using MVC5 and I am importing my excel file using epplus into sql database. However I am able to import files which are smaller in size like less than 1000kb but any file size larger then that is taking hours to import. I am looking for a efficient way to import my excel file in a more quicker

```
public ActionResult Application(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        var usersList = new List<bomApplicationImportTgt>();
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                {
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                        var user = new bomApplicationImportTgt();
                        user.date = Convert.ToDateTime(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value);
                        user.Description = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SequenceNumber = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value);
                        user.PartNumber = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PartsName = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SP = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value?.ToString();
                        user.INT = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 7].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SN = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 8].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SZ = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 9].Value?.ToString();
                        user.C = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 10].Value?.ToString();
                        user.E_F = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 11].Value?.ToString();
                        user.Block = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 12].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SEC = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value?.ToString();
                        user.Item = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 14].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SUF = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 15].Value?.ToString();
                        user.Model = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 16].Value?.ToString();
                        user.M_E_F = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 17].Value?.ToString();
                        user.OP = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 18].Value?.ToString();
                        user.Type = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 19].Value?.ToString();
                        user.Quantity = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 20].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PLGRPCD = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 21].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PL1 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 22].Value?.ToString();
                        user.ATC1 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 23].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PL2 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 24].Value?.ToString();
                        user.ATC2 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 25].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PL3 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 26].Value?.ToString();
                        user.ATC3 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 27].Value?.ToString();
                        user.Plant = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 28].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SHR = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 29].Value?.ToString();
                        user.DC_Number = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 30].Value?.ToString();
                        user.FileName = fileName;
                        usersList.Add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        using (Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities excelImportDBEntities = new Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in usersList)
            {
                excelImportDBEntities.bomApplicationImportTgts.Add(item);
            }
            excelImportDBEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View("Application");
    }
```

Comment: How do you write the data to the database?

Comment: I have edited my question and added my code in it.

Comment: You are using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes I am using Entity Framework 6.

Comment: I assume writing to the database is the slow part . Than you need to bulk insert the data to the database. For EF you can use a lib such as https://github.com/vitorortuondo/EntityFramework.BulkInsert (Nuget search for efBulkInsert) Or use  [SQlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8) directly.

Comment: I am not sure how to use either of those libraries? I am relatively new to coding

Comment: Try using filehelpers and SQLBulkCopy. 

We import 30 million+ records in about a minute

Comment: I have installed both the libraries through nuget manager.

Comment: @Marcel-Is-Hier I am importing the excel file and then importing it to sql.

Comment: @Marcel-Is-Hier can you please provide any link to it with example?

Comment: I am trying to use epplus so that I dont have to install anything on my server

Comment: @Minhal https://www.filehelpers.net/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.

Filehelpers is a nuget package. BulkCopy is a standard .net library. 

Filehelpers has some excellent documentation on how to use. SQL bulk copy also has an example on the page. Lemme know if you need further help

Comment: @Marcel-Is-Hier ok I will look into it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the ExcelDataReader library, you can add it through Nuget. On your model you just need a byte array to hold the spreadsheet data and the path of the spreadsheet. To add it right click on your solution and select Manage Nuget Packages. Then search for ExcelDataReader and install it.

Here's the model you're uploading:

```
public class SpreadsheetUploadModel
{
public byte[] Payload {get; set;}
public string FileName {get; set;}
}
```

Here's the basic idea of your action, I don't have a return in there because I'm not sure what you want to return.

```
    public IActionResult UploadSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetUploadModel mySheet)
    {
        IExcelDataReader rdr = null;
                    try
                    {
                            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(mySheet.Payload)) //Payload is the byte array
                            {
                                ms.Position = 0;
                                string ext = Path.GetExtension(mySheet.FileName); //filename is the filename

                                switch (ext)
                                {
                                    case ".xls": //Old style (2003 or less)
                                        rdr = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(ms);
                                        break;
                                    case ".xlsx": //New style (2007 or higher)
                                        rdr = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(ms);
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(String.Format("File extension {0} is not recognized as valid", ext));
                                }

                                using (DataSet ds = rdr.AsDataSet())
                                {
                                    int rowNumber = 2;
                                    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                                    DataView dv = ds.DefaultViewManager.CreateDataView(ds.Tables[0]);

                                    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                                    { //... logic in here - you can iterate the rows which will map the spreadsheet rows, so you can insert each row individually, or build a different model that your database function is expecting, or whatever else you're trying to do ... 
}
                                 }
                            }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }

    }
```

Comment: will it look something like this? I am really new to coding.

Comment: I am not able to figure this out

Comment: You're already getting the byte array, the major difference is I use a model and you're using a form collection which I'm somewhat unfamiliar with. You can google something like "How to use ExcelDataReader with FormCollection" and maybe that can fill in the missing pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Probably inserting to the database is what is slowing you down. Use SqlBulkCopy to speed things up. (You need to ass a reference to `FastMember` for the `ObjectReader`)

```
public class BulkWriter
{
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping[]> ColumnMapping =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping[]>();

        public async Task InsertAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string tableName, SqlConnection connection,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(items))
            {
                bulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                foreach (var colMap in GetColumnMappings<T>())
                    bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(colMap);
                await bulk.WriteToServerAsync(reader, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping> GetColumnMappings<T>() =>
            ColumnMapping.GetOrAdd(typeof(T),
                type => 
                    type.GetProperties()
                        .Select(p => new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(p.Name, p.Name)).ToArray());
}
```

Usage:

```
await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "TheNameOfTheTable", excelImportDBEntities.Database.Connection, CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: you are suggesting to use this code and replace it with the existing one?

Comment: The code provided above is written in my controller. so do you want me to use the bulk writer class instead ?

Comment: Instead of adding your users to the EF db context you call InsertAsync with you user list.

Comment: using (Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities excelImportDBEntities = new Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities())
            {
                foreach (var item in usersList)
                {
                    await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomApplicationImportTgts", excelImportDBEntities.Database.Connection, CancellationToken.None);;
                }
                excelImportDBEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View("Application");

Comment: is this what you meant?

Comment: No, you dont need to loop the usersList. Just send it in. And you dont need to call SaveChanges

Comment: using (Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities excelImportDBEntities = new Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities())
            {await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomApplicationImportTgts", excelImportDBEntities.Database.Connection, CancellationToken.None);
             }
            return View("Application");
        }

Comment: do you mean like this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Import in my project like below:

```
  using Excel;
  var importFile = Request.Files["files"];
  if (importFile.ContentLength == 0)
  {
       ViewBag.errorFileMessage = "Please select file";
       return View();
  }
  Stream stream = importFile.InputStream;
  IExcelDataReader reader = null;
  reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
  reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
  DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
  DataTable dataRecords = new DataTable();
  //You can also remove empty rows 
  if (result.Tables.Count > 0)
  {
      dataRecords = result.Tables[0];
      for (int i = dataRecords.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
          if (dataRecords.Rows[i][0] == DBNull.Value)
          {
              dataRecords.Rows[i].Delete();
          }
          dataRecords.AcceptChanges();
      }
   }
   if (dataRecords.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
        List<MyExcelListModel> reqData = new List<MyExcelListModel>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataRecords.Rows)
        {
            MyExcelModel exceldata = new MyExcelModel();
            exceldata.Name= row[0].ToString();
            //Add according to your requirements
            reqData.Add(exceldata);
        }     
   }
```

Now you can save the data into database.